# Terminal (zsh) prompt not showing up

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh

I am using zsh on my Macbook, but sometimes out of nowhere the terminal prompt just doesn't show up when I launch it, and only restarting the computer fixes that. Any ideas about what could be causing this behavior? Is there a way for me to reload zsh w/o needing to restart the computer?

Zsh config file: https://gist.github.com/zilton7/e5feb4993a9b334aacc5279603ff7cd9

PS I can run bash with no problem whatsoever.